# How do I render a formatted comment inside a function in RMD?

Tags: r-markdown

I created a R file `testRMD.R` with the following content:

```
#' # Comment outside function

nested_comment_inside <- function(){
  #' # Comment inside function
}

nested_comment_inside()
```

Then when I run the instruction `rmarkdown::render("testRMD.R")`, the generated `testRMD.html` displays `Comment outside function` well formatted as expected, but not `Comment inside function`.

Is there a way to get `Comment inside function` displayed in html every time I call `nested_comment_inside()` ?

Comment: Comments aren't displayed when functions are executed normally.  If you want something displayed when you execute a function, you have to output it somehow.  I'm not sure the best form of output when rendering a `.R` file; maybe someone else can answer this.